# Write on HDFS using Python

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to write on HDFS from Python.
Right now, I am using https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html
but for large file I get back:

```
    File "/home/edge7/venv-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hdfs/client.py", line 400, in write
    consumer(data)
  File "/home/edge7/venv-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hdfs/client.py", line 394, in consumer
    auth=False,
  File "/home/edge7/venv-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hdfs/client.py", line 179, in _request
    **kwargs
  File "/home/edge7/venv-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/edge7/venv-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/edge7/venv-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))
```

My code for writing is pretty simple:

```
client = InsecureClient('http://xxxxxxx.co:50070', user='hdfs')
client.write("/tmp/a",stringToWrite)
```

Anyone can suggest a decent package to write on HDFS?
Cheers

Comment: Are you sure you can access the machine by the hostname and are you sure the port 50070 is open?

Comment: yes, it writes for a while but suddenly stop and I receive the above error

Comment: I'd bet on a DNS problem. It sounds like the host name of one of your datanodes isn't resolvable. Everything would work fine until your namenode directs your app to write a block to the datanode with the unresolvable name.

Answer (score 0):

For the stacktrace, it seems to be security related. Are you sure you need to use the InsecureClient and not the Kerberos one?. Also, remember that library is just a binding for HttpFs, so doing a manual test with Postman or CURL would let you debug any issue cluster-side.